# XSL Autonumbering

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Given the following structure,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<crew>
  <crewDrill>
    <step>
      <if>
        <step></step>
        <step></step>
      </if>
    </step>
    <if>
      <step>
        <if>
          <step></step>
          <step></step>
        </if>
      </step>
    </if>
  </crewDrill>
  <crewDrill>
    <step>
      <if>
        <step></step>
        <step></step>
      </if>
    </step>
    <if>
      <step></step>
      <step></step>
    </if>
  </crewDrill>
</crew>
```

I would like to use xsl 1.0 to autonumber by adding an attribute to each `<step>` node. I want to use multiple levels and restart numbering at the start of each `<crew>` element. More specifically, I would like to get the following result:

```
<crew>
  <crewDrill>
    <step nb="1">
      <if>
        <step nb="1.1"></step>
        <step nb="1.2"></step>
      </if>
    </step>
    <if>
      <step nb="2">
        <if>
          <step nb="2.1"></step>
          <step nb="2.2"></step>
        </if>
      </step>
    </if>
  </crewDrill>
  <crewDrill>
    <step nb="1">
      <if>
        <step nb="1.1"></step>
        <step nb="1.2"></step>
      </if>
    </step>
    <if>
      <step nb="2"></step>
      <step nb="2"></step>
    </if>
  </crewDrill>
</crew>
```

I have tried the following with no success:

```
<xsl:template match="step">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="proceduralStepNumber">
        <xsl:number format="1. " level="multiple" from="crewDrill"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: The numbering scheme is inconsistent.  The `step nb="2"` is not at the same hierarchical level as `step nb="1"`.  This appears to confuse the `xsl:number` element.

Comment: You are right Jim, but in my scenario I'm trying to do the numbering of the step elements, ignoring any other elements. Is there an easy way to do it using xsl?

Comment: Probably a LOT easier in XSLT2